# Running java selenium project in parallel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, ui-automation, parallel-testing

I am new to parallel testing (I am using java selenium with TestNG as my project framework).

when I launch parallel testing using my pom.xml file I can see that browsers opened for me but the logic is happening only in one browser (so I can see that the input for the login page for example is being executed only in one browser), at the beginning I had static WebDriver instance so I changed it to be dynamic.

This is my pom.xml file (partial, I did not copied the dependencies part):

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
<!--                    <suiteXmlFiles> will be added in AUT-98-->
<!--                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>-->
<!--                    </suiteXmlFiles>-->
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>reg</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>critical</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <debugForkedProcess>true</debugForkedProcess>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>critical_tests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                       </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

this is my testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Automation_Suite" parallel="methods">
    <test name="Critical tests to run after DEV deploy build">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="critical"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.hackeruso.automation.ui.cms.categories.CategoriesTest"/>
            <class name="com.hackeruso.automation.ui.cms.content_manager.ContentManagerPresentationTest"/>
            <class name="com.hackeruso.automation.ui.cms.cyberpedia.CyberpediaCategoriesTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And this is how I initialized my webdriver (method from BaseTest) which being extended from all test classes):

```
 @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public final void BaseTestSetUp(ITestContext context) throws IOException {
        driver = DriverWrapper.open(BROWSER, TEST_OUTPUT_FOLDER);
        DriverFactory.getInstance().setDriver(driver);
        driver = DriverFactory.getInstance().getDriver();
     
    }
```

This is the 'open' method which init the webdriver:

```
public class DriverWrapper implements WebDriver {

private WebDriver driver;

private DriverWrapper(WebDriver driver){
   this.driver = driver;
  }

public static DriverWrapper open(Browser browser, File downloadsFolder) {
        Log.info(String.format("Starting new %s browser driver", browser));
        switch (browser) {
            case FIREFOX:
                return createFireFoxInst();
            case CHROME:
                return createChromeInst(downloadsFolder);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("'" + browser + "'no such browser type");
    }
}

private static DriverWrapper createFireFoxInst() {
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    options.setHeadless((EnvConf.getAsBoolean("selenium.headless")));
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return new DriverWrapper(driver);
}


private static DriverWrapper createChromeInst(File downloadsFolder){
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setHeadless(EnvConf.getAsBoolean("selenium.headless"));
    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    options.addArguments("--lang=" + EnvConf.getProperty("selenium.locale"));

    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.SEVERE);

    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    options.addArguments("--window-size=" + EnvConf.getProperty("selenium.window_size"));

    ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 

    return new DriverWrapper(driver);
   }
 }
```

I am using `mvn test -Pcritical` to run my tests.
**Expected results**: expected number of browsers will be open and will start to run different class tests in parallel.

**Actual results**: expected number of browsers opened, but interactions are being done only on one browser.

I don't understand what was going wrong, first I declared webdriver as static and then I changed it to non-static variable and still not working as expected. I can provide more chunks of code if needed.